# Code execution hangs while trying to retrieve disk details from GCP cloud using discovery method?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, disk

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery


def main():

    cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("json file path")

    service = discovery.build("compute", "v1", credentials=cred)
    request = service.disks().list(project="projectid", zone="us-central1-a")
    print(request)
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
    print(response)
    for disk in response["items"]:
        # TODO: Change code below to process each `disk` resource:
        print(disk)

    request = service.disks().list_next(
        previous_request=request, previous_response=response
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code is successfully able to print(request) data after which there is no result. I have as disk created in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a while loop in the code without the termination clause. Thats where its getting stuck. You could rewrite that part in the following way:

```py
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()

    for disk in response['items']:
        # TODO: Change code below to process each `disk` resource:
        print(disk)

    request = service.disks().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Comment: .That solved the problem. Strange that this is the code that is in the google doc. [Google docs to handle disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/list). Maybe it was expected for us to handle it.

Comment: That code is also correct because there is a termination condition being set in the form request being called again in the block. In your case the code block for `for disk in response['items']:` is outside the while block whereas in the code sample it is inside the while block.

Comment: May be while copy pasting the while block would have shifted. I have updated my answer to reflect the code sample in the doc.

Comment: Yes, I had misplaced it during the copy paste. Thanks.